# Error in defining constraints using IloRange in CPLEX (c++)

Tags: c++, constraints, cplex

I am facing problem in writing constraints using IloRange. There are no compilation error but the code is not running.

In the code, ad_sales.u_j[j] is a variable, while demand[j] and lambda[j] are parameters. The syntax I have used for ILoRange is ilorange(env, lower bound, variable, upper bound).

I need to find duals of a set of constraint, which is why i switched to IloRange. If I use the following command instead of Ilorange the code is running fine.

```
for(IloInt j=0; j<data.n; j++)
model_ad.add(ad_sales.u_j[j] <= demand[j]*lambda[j]);
```

But following is not working:

```
IloRangeArray cons(env, data.n); 
for(IloInt j=0; j<data.n; j++)
{
    cons.add(IloRange(env, 0, ad_sales.u_j[j],demand[j]*lambda[j]));
    //model_ad.add(cons[j]);
}
model_ad.add(cons);
```

Really appreciate the help.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `IloExpr` like you did before, i.e.,

```
IloRangeArray cons(env, data.n); 
for(IloInt j=0; j<data.n; j++) {
    cons.add(d_sales.u_j[j] <= demand[j]*lambda[j]);
}
model_ad.add(cons);
```

The problem with your way is that `IloRange` expects `IloNumExprArg`, not just `IloNumVar`.

**Edit:**

`add()` method of `IloModel` expects `IloExtractableArray`. I tried to add a constraint object to `IloRangeArray` and got `no matching function for call to ‘IloRangeArray::add(IloConstraint&)’` error message. I would suggest to use `IloConstraintArray`, e.g.

```
IloConstraintArray cons(env); 
for(IloInt j=0; j<data.n; j++) {
    cons.add(d_sales.u_j[j] <= demand[j]*lambda[j]);
}
model_ad.add(cons);
```

It worked with my example.

Comment: I tried your suggested method, the constraints are getting added in the IloRange array, but the code is unable to add them in the model_ad. The code stops working at `model_ad.add(cons)`

Comment: I really appreciate the help......I tried `IloConstraintArray cons(env)` method.... It is working fine.. But the problem is I want to get duals of those constraint set. The getDual expects an IloRangeArray and is not working with an IloConstraintArray .... The code stops at            `for(IloInt j=0; j<data.n; j++)
    cout<<cplex_ad.getDual(cons[j])<<endl;`

Comment: Well, in that case populate your `cons` array first, then add constraints one by one in a cycle `for(IloInt j=0; j<data.n; j++) { model.add(cons[i]); }`

Comment: I tried doing that, but again while running the code, it is stopping  at addition of constraints to the model.....

Answer (score 0):

After facing this issue and quite some debugging, I found the issue (at least for my case).

The thing is, `IloRangeArray cons(env, data.n);` seems to populate `cons` with  `data.n` "empty" `IloRange` objects. (By "empty", I mean that the object is there according to the debugger, but its `_impl` field is set to null).

So, when calling `cons.add(...)`, it is *appending to these existing empty constraints*. Which means you end up with a bunch of empty IloRange objects, followed by the actual constraints you are adding.

This messes up the call to `model_ad.add(cons);` and causes a segmentation fault (at least in my case).

---

#### Solution

What worked for me: Declaring the `IloRangeArray` **without** setting the size parameter, i.e. using:

```
IloRangeArray cons(env);
```

Instead of

```
IloRangeArray cons(env, data.n);
```

Hope this helps any future reader.